# Material UI Select: "You have provided an out-of-range value"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Excuse my cluelessness please, I got handed a bunch of code which looks like this (simplified):

```
const MyComponent = ({valueProp}=>{

    return(
        <TextField
            ...
            select
            value={valueProp?valueProp:''}
        >
           ...
        </TextField>
    )
});
```

I'm supposed to fix this error:

> "Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value `8` for the
> select component. Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
> The available values are "".

Does anyone know why this happens/how to fix it? I console logged valueProp right before rendering and it looks like it's getting updated from a parent component. On the first render, when `value` is `''`, no warnings show up. Then when `valueProp` gets updated to equal `8`, my console logs are throwing that complaint. Are the acceptable values here based on the values in the select (TextField) on mount/first render? (That sounds awful...)

Comment: Can you show the menu items array? What it seems is that your setting the value to 8 but you do not have a <MenuItem value={8}>description..</MenuItem>

Comment: Oh... that gets rendered according to some other prop too

Comment: So value on TextField is the currently selected one then? I DID NOT KNOW THAT THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!